# why i'm permanently logged off my be

Tags: typo3

Hello i have a problem with BE in my system. I'm permanently and automaticly logged out it after some time. 10-15 seconds, sometimes faster, sometimes slower. It's not connected with beeing idle cause I can be logged off even when I'm checking page tree or saving records

I've set lock ip on 1 but it didn't help. The problem is most common under Firefox or Chome, what is strange under internet explorer i don't see it as often

Other strange thing is that I see it on my live version but when I'm working on my local copy it doen not occure

TYPO3 version 4.6.4

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible reasons, why that happens. You need to separate possible factors.

Some hints:

- close browser, then open Browswer with only one tab with your backend. Does it still happen? (Do not enter the frontend) If that works, do one step after another. Open frontend in another tab etc.
- Do you have an Proxy / a Firewall? Is it possible to deactivate them for a short time? Try it
- Are there any JavaScript errors?
- are there any HTTP errors? You can check that in your Webserver-Logfiles for your IP. On IE i had that issue with an missing favicon!
- Check the content of your cookies - which domain is set for your cookies.